# How do I spread out this navbar along with making the links exclusive to the button itself?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, navbar, nav

I'm trying to get each button separate from each other. Also if you put your mouse to the right of the navbar the link is still clickable, how can I remove this?

Here's the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dc88h246/) link

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Me</title>
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
<section class="main_front">
<nav class="nav_container">
<div class="nav_links">
<div class="logo"><img src="../images/logo.png" height="65px" /></div><!--end of logo-->
<ul class="right_links">
<a href="#"><li class="nav_li">Schedule</li></a>
<a href="#"><li class="nav_li">Summer</li></a>
<a href="#"><li class="nav_li">Web Design</li></a>
<a href="#"><li class="nav_li">School</li></a>
<a href="#"><li class="nav_li">Whatever</li></a>
</ul><!--end of right_links-->
</div><!--end of nav_links-->
</nav><!--end of nav_container-->
</section><!--end of main_front-->

<section class="footer">
<div class="phonenumber">
<b>Contact:</b> XXX-XXX-XXXX
</div><!--end of phonenumber-->

<div class="address">
1234 Web Design Ave.
</div><!--end of address-->
</section><!--end of footer-->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
margin:0;
margin:none;    
}

.logo {
font-family: stalemate, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:36px;
float:left;
margin-top:5px; 
}

.main_front {
width:100%;
height:650px;
background-color:#A9D2F1;   
}

.nav_links {
width:1600px;
height:100px;
margin:auto;
color:white;    
}



.nav_container {
width:100%;
height:79px;    
position:fixed;
background-color:#82B5E8;
}

.right_links {
width:600px;
float:right;
position:relative;
}

.right_links a {
display:inline-block;
list-style-type:none;
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
font-size:17px;
margin-top:15px;
font-family:Montserrat, "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}

.right_links li {
width:130px;
height:40px;
background-color:#82B5E8;   
line-height:40px;
text-align:center;  
border-radius:15px;
transition:all 0.5s;
-moz-transition:all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition:all 0.5s;
-ms-transition:all 0.5s;
margin-left:-260px;
}

.nav_li {
margin-right:200px; 
}

.right_links li:hover {
background-color:#166083;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I'm trying to get each button separate from each other.
A:I changed your nav.nav_container tag to a div#nav_container tag, and removed the div.nav_links. It seemed to work against you, then I updated the style sheet accordingly.

2) Also if you put your mouse to the right of the navbar the link is still clickable, how can I remove this?
A: open your list items first, and then nest your anchors in those, you have them backwards so you're probably getting several errors, but you're definitely getting hyperlinks where you don't want them.  This will put the links on the text inside your nav items.

NOTE: Also changed your *{styles}; to body{styles}; typically you want to stay away from "*"
as a universal class, later on in your page's maturation you'll find it can hurt performance.

HTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Me</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
    <body>

        <section class="main_front">
            <div id="nav_container">
                    <div class="logo"><img src="../images/logo.png" height="65px" alt="My logo" /></div><!--end of logo-->
                    <ul class="right_links">
                        <li class="nav_li"><a href="#">Schedule</a></li>
                        <li class="nav_li"><a href="#">Summer</a></li>
                        <li class="nav_li"><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                        <li class="nav_li"><a href="#">School</a></li>
                        <li class="nav_li"><a href="#">Whatever</a></li>
                    </ul><!--end of right_links-->
            </div><!--end of nav_container-->
        </section><!--end of main_front-->

        <section class="footer">
            <div class="phonenumber">
                <b>Contact:</b> XXX-XXX-XXXX
            </div><!--end of phonenumber-->

            <div class="address">
                1234 Web Design Ave.
            </div><!--end of address-->
        </section><!--end of footer-->
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body{
    margin:0px;
}

.logo {
float:left;
margin-top:5px; 
}

.main_front {
width:100%;
height:650px;
background-color:#A9D2F1;   
}

#nav_container {
width:100%;
height:79px;    
background-color:#82B5E8;
}

/* .nav_links {
width:1600px;
height:100px;
margin:auto;
color:white;    
} */

.nav_li {
margin-right:20px; 
float:right;
}

.right_links {
width:70%;
float:right;
list-style-type:none;
}

.right_links li {
width:130px;
height:40px;
background-color:#82B5E8;   
line-height:40px;
text-align:center; 
margin-right:10px;   
border-radius:15px;
transition:all 0.5s;
-moz-transition:all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition:all 0.5s;
-ms-transition:all 0.5s;
}

.right_links li:hover {
background-color:#166083;
}   

.right_links li a {
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
font-size:17px;
margin-top:15px;
font-family:Montserrat, "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}
```

Hope it helps!